# Validação de byte através de array de bits de uma imagem

Tags: java, hexadecimal, io

Estou tentando efetuar a validação de uma imagem recebida numa pasta FTP. As imagens começam com os bytes "FFD8" e terminam com a sequência "FFD9" para que haja a possibilidade realizar a verificação.

Estou recebendo a imagem num `BufferedImage` e convertendo para um array de bytes, entretanto, quando acesso as posições iniciais deste array nunca correspondem ao valor de FFD8, recebo valores como 001F 0019. Realizei a verificação destes mesmos arquivos em editores como sublimetext e alguns hexdumps e neles os bytes iniciais e finais correspondem com o valor correto "FFD8" (Inicial) e "FFD9" (Final). Neste pequeno trecho de código estou concatenando tudo numa `StringBuilder`. O que eu poderia estar fazendo de errado?

```
void startProcessBloco(){
    int qtdBloco = 0;
    File fList[] = diretorio.listFiles();
     for ( int i = 0; i < fList.length; i++ ){
         //Validação verificando se o vetor não é nulo
         if(fList.length > i + 3){
             if(fList[i].getName().contains("_1") && fList[i+3].getName().contains("_4")){

                 try {
                        File imagemFisica = new File(dir+fList[i].getName());
                        BufferedImage imagemEmBuffer = ImageIO.read(imagemFisica);
                        byte[] imagemEmBytes = bloco.extractBytes(imagemEmBuffer);
                        bloco.getImagens().add(imagemEmBuffer);

                        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                        for (byte b : imagemEmBytes) {
                            sb.append(String.format("%04X ", b));
                        }
                        System.out.println(sb.toString());

                        ImageIO.write(imagemEmBuffer, "jpg",
                                new File("D:\\testesBlocoFtp\\recebeImg\\" + fList[i].getName()));

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
             }
         }
     }
     System.out.println(qtdBloco);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acabei por resolver meu problema usando as seguintes bibliotecas:

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex;
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
```

Com  a commons.io.IOUtils a transformação da InputStream, que no código anterior era recebido através de um objeto da classe File se tornou bem mais fácil:

```
byte[] imagemEmBytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(imagemFisica);
```

E com a commons.codec.binary.Hex a transformação do array de bytes em uma string em Hex retornou o valor correto numa string com o código hexa da imagem. Depois foi só realizar a validação:

```
if (Hex.encodeHexString(imagemEmBytes).startsWith("ffd8") &&
    Hex.encodeHexString(imagemEmBytes).endsWith("ffd9")) {
    //Minha imagem foi validada, faço oque quiser com ela aqui.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No seu código há isso:

```
if(fList[i].getName().contains("_1") && fList[i+3].getName().contains("_4")){
```

Este `fList[i]` e este `fList[i+3]` me dizem que você espera que os elementos no array estejam em uma deteminada ordem. Entretanto no [Javadocs do método listFiles()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles--) está escrito:

> There is no guarantee that the name strings in the resulting array will appear in any specific order; they are not, in particular, guaranteed to appear in alphabetical order.

Que traduzindo para o português é:

> Não há garantia que as strings com os nomes no array resultante irão aparecer em qualquer ordem específica; eles não são, em particular, garantidos de aparecer em ordem alfabética.

Além disso, bytes em Java vão de -128 até 127, diferentemente do que a maioria esperaria que é de 0 até 255. E você está usando isso:

```
String.format("%04X ", b)
```

Vamos ver o que isso imprime com alguns bytes:

```
System.out.println(String.format("%04X ", (byte) -128));
System.out.println(String.format("%04X ", (byte) -127));
System.out.println(String.format("%04X ", (byte) -40));
System.out.println(String.format("%04X ", (byte) -39));
System.out.println(String.format("%04X ", (byte) -2));
System.out.println(String.format("%04X ", (byte) -1));
System.out.println(String.format("%04X ", (byte) 0));
System.out.println(String.format("%04X ", (byte) 1));
System.out.println(String.format("%04X ", (byte) 31));
System.out.println(String.format("%04X ", (byte) 25));
System.out.println(String.format("%04X ", (byte) 126));
System.out.println(String.format("%04X ", (byte) 127));
System.out.println(String.format("%04X ", (byte) 128));
System.out.println(String.format("%04X ", (byte) 129));
System.out.println(String.format("%04X ", (byte) 216));
System.out.println(String.format("%04X ", (byte) 217));
System.out.println(String.format("%04X ", (byte) 254));
System.out.println(String.format("%04X ", (byte) 255));
```

Eis a saída:

```
0080 
0081 
00D8 
00D9 
00FE 
00FF 
0000 
0001 
001F 
0019 
007E 
007F 
0080 
0081 
00D8 
00D9 
00FE 
00FF
```

Bem, Usando `"%04X "`, você SEMPRE verá os dois primeiros dígitos serem zeros. Talvez `"%02 "` faça mais sentido. O `001F` corresponde ao 31, o `0019` corresponde ao 25. O `00D8` corresponde ao -40 (ou 216) e o `00D9` corresponde ao -39 (ou 217). Note o seguinte:

```
System.out.println(String.format("%04X ", (short) -40));
System.out.println(String.format("%04X ", (short) -39));
```

Eis a saída:

```
FFD8
FFD9
```

São os mesmos valores -40 e -39, mas representados como `short` ao invés de `byte`.

Sei que isso ainda não soluciona o seu problema por completo, mas deve te ajudar.

Comment: Ajudou muito, a partir da sua resposta comecei a pensar numa direção diferente e após pesquisar um pouco mais, encontrei duas bibliotecas que caíram como uma luva .